# Add a horizontal scrollbar to an image with the animation?

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile-safari, responsive

How could I add a horizontal scrollbar to be available for when the user resizes the browser window (I need this to work especially on mobile!), the user can scroll horizontally to see the full image and it pauses the animation when they hover, swipe on it.

I am using this for a family photo on my family's website. Is this possible with CSS or if not, Javascript?

```css
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
#animate-area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/open_graph/github-mark.png);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="animate-area"></div>
```